# XPath to select element with class wildcard?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Is there any possible XPath for selecting an item using a wildcard?  For example, I tried `//img[@class='poly *']` to select these `img` elements,

```
<img class="poly x1" title="title1"> 
<img class="poly x2" title="title2"> 
<img class="poly x3" title="title3">
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` is not a wildcard in XPath, so

```
//img[@class='poly *']
```

is going to match all `img` elements with `class` attribute values exactly equal to `poly *` – literally ending with a `*` character.

You might instead use

```
//img[starts-with(@class,'poly')]
```

or the more robust idiom for allowing `poly` to appear anywhere in the value of the `class` attribute, without matching `polymorphism` et. al. by mistake:

```
//img[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' poly ')]
```

Note: XPath 2.0 has a `matches()` function that supports regular expressions.